# Waiting mouse cursor in my GWT application stays infinitely (only in Chrome, only in Production)

Tags: gwt

Could you please tell me why I have waiting mouse cursor in my gwt application as if page not fully loaded ? It doesn't happen on dev server. It only happens in production. Also it's happening in Chrome but doesn't in IE.

Link to my app is [**here**](http://goo.gl/TZyyR).

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm using chrome and i don't see a loading cursor anywhere, arrow most of time and the pointer on buttons... I am using version 17.0.963.56 m of chrome on a Win7 64bit is there any difference to your set up there?

Comment: I have same build. I also disabled all extensions. It's Windows 7 x64. I added screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it again in Chrome, but for me no wait cursor is Displayed. But i think, your Google Chrome is trying to open the Google Translate Menu. For me it came quickly and the page loading stopped and the mouse was at normal position.

I prefer you try updating your chrome.

I have also checked the same in my co-workers Laptop and its working fine too.

[image: Screenshot]

If problem still persists, please use CCleaner Software and clear all Temporary files, Browser Cache, Recent files etc. Why because, GWT creates a lot of temporary files which may reduce your system performance. So after each cleaning, just restart the system also. I had few such resolutions recently.

Answer (score 0):

I opened your link in Firefox and got the following error

> ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml module file. The compile
>   time user.agent value (safari) does not match the runtime user.agent
>   value (gecko1_8). Expect more errors

This is because, you have compiled your code for Webkit browsers only. If you have added a line as below in your gwt module xml file,

```
<define-property name="user.agent" values="ie6">
```

you may either remove it or you can add more browser support via this.

Comment: I know. I left only Chrome because I want it to compile faster while I'm in development :) Is there anything you can suggest regarding my question ?

Comment: the same when i opened in chrome, it was working fine. It showed me a form which used a different language. I am using Chrome 17.0.963.66. Can you just describe more about the issue?

Comment: I have same build. I also disabled all extensions. It's Windows 7 x64. I added screenshot to my question.